# How to have Guice call methods and inject the paramaters for me?

Tags: java, json, guice

So I'm tackling the following issue as part of some course homework:

My program receives tweets in different formats and saves them for all sorts of queries. The main class is called `TwitterKnowledgeCenter` and it handles most of the application logic.

As of now it can receive the tweets in two formats:

1. Some line format where each tweet looks like: `15/05/2013 13:08:08, 334611146092994560`
2. A JSON format (which I think is officially from twitter): `{"created_at":"Wed May 15 10:08:07 +0000 2013","id":3346111419..}`

I want the `TwitterKnowledgeCenter` to import the  tweets using a call like:

```
String[] lines = ...
TwitterKnowledgeCenter tw = new TwitterKnowledgeCenter(...);
tw.import(lines, lineparser)
```

where `lines` represents tweets in format #1 and `lineparser` is an instance of class implementing an `TweetParser` interface which can parse tweets from format #1 to `Tweet` objects which the `TwitterKnowledgeCenter` holds.

I want the user of the TwitterKnowledgeCenter to be able to freely swap tweet formats. This means that he should be able to use `tw.import(lines, lineparser)` and `tw.import(jsonTweets, jsonparser)` interchangeably.

How can I achieve this with Guice? 
I thought the code should look something like this at first:

```
String[] lines = ....
String[] jsonTweets = ..
TwitterKnowledgeCenter tw = new TwitterKnowledgeCenter(...);
bind(TweetParser.class).to(JsonParser.class);
<what to write here that'll call tw.import()>
```

It seems though that Guice will have to handle calling the method `import()` based on the binding. How is this achieved or is it not possible?

Is there a different way to structure this that makes sense and will work?

Answer (score 0):

All right, here is something you have to do.

1.Create two different **guice modules** that contains the bindings for each of your tweet format i.e. line and Json

**LineTweetModule.java**

```
public class LineTweetModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {

     bind(TweetParser.class).to(LineParser.class);   
  }
}
```

**JsonTweetModule.java**

```
public class JsonTweetModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {

     bind(TweetParser.class).to(JsonParser.class);   
  }
}
```

2.Assuming the class **TwitterKnowledgeCenter** has a constructor that takes the TweetParser as a paramter. You need to annotate that 
constructor with the **@inject** in order to explicityly get invoked by Guice

**TwitterKnowledgeCenter.java**

```
  @inject
    public TwitterKnowledgeCenter(TweetParser parser) {

    }
```

3.Now in your client code, you need to crate an injector for the respective tweet format

```
// To import line format tweets
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new LineTweetModule());

TwitterKnowledgeCenter tw = injector.getInstance(TwitterKnowledgeCenter.class);

String[] lines = {},
tw.import(line);

// To import Json format tweets
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JsonTweetModule());

TwitterKnowledgeCenter tw = injector.getInstance(TwitterKnowledgeCenter.class);

String[] lines = {},
tw.import(line);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the `TwitterKnowledgeCenter` will have to be the same after changing the parser. Won't I have to change the getInstance method to "set" the parser to the one I passed to the createInjector()?

Comment: No, That's what the point of using google guice. You are already binding the LineTweetParser and JsonTweetParser into their own modules. Since, these two parses are implemented by TweetParser interface, you just need to pass TweetParser to the TwitterKnowledgeCenter constructor. Behind the scenes, guice creates the instance for respective format and you can call the import method on the instance. Not only it hides the implementation but also makes your code more testable and modular.

Comment: Ya but the second call to `getInsance` will create a new `TwitterKnowledgeCenter` instance (without the original one's data) won't it?